# Help identifying a weed/unwanted plant that pops up all over and unchecked, grows into a tree!

Tags: identification, weed-control, weeds, invasive

Per the title really.

- It seems to be quite invasive and pops up all over the place, often entangled into the centre of an existing shrub
- It's a pain to dig out but it can be done
- It's quite (but not completely) resistant to home-use weedkillers
- The bark strips off the stem quite easily when you try to pull it up
- The stem feels somewhat like a eucalyptus - fast growing wood - when cut with secateurs
- It's very fast-growing
- It happily regrows when cut near the base, from just below the cut
- It seems to be quite widespread locally (Berkshire, UK)
- In other people's gardens, there are unchecked examples, and it's well over 10 feet tall - looking a lot like an established tree

I'm wondering:

- what it is
- what, if anything, can I do about it, that I'm not doing already.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

[image: Picture 4]

Comment: Does it bloom? White?

Comment: I've not seen it bloom in previous years elsewhere around here - and I've certainly not let it do so!

Answer (score 4):

It seems a *Fraxinus excelior* (Ash). It grows fast and it likes stony places (like walls, streets).

Young trees sometime have such reddish look (trunk, branches), especially on dry places.

Comment: Yep, could be that. Looks pretty close. Just keep digging?

Comment: It looks as if it is a seedling from a nearby tree.  Easy peasy just to pull out.  No problems with invasive roots.  Look around for a tree with the same leaves...let us know!